# CMake build calling SWIG with multiple arguments

Tags: cmake, swig

I can successfully build a SWIG module using CMake, e.g. given an the trivial example.i:

```
%module example
```

and an empty example.cxx the following is sufficient to compile an empty but otherwise working Python module:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

FIND_PACKAGE(SWIG REQUIRED)
INCLUDE(${SWIG_USE_FILE})

FIND_PACKAGE(PythonLibs)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH})
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

SET(CMAKE_SWIG_FLAGS "-Wall")

SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(example.i PROPERTIES CPLUSPLUS ON)
SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(example.i PROPERTIES SWIG_FLAGS "-builtin")

SWIG_ADD_MODULE(example python example.i example.cxx)
SWIG_LINK_LIBRARIES(example ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

If I want to pass more options to SWIG when it gets called during the build the obvious solution is to change the CMakeLists.txt:

```
SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(example.i PROPERTIES SWIG_FLAGS "-py3 -builtin -extranative")
```

but this doesn't work, the build now fails with:

```
[ 33%] Swig source
swig error : Unrecognized option -py3 -builtin -extranative
Use 'swig -help' for available options.
make[2]: *** [examplePYTHON_wrap.cxx] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/_example.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

And running the build with `VERBOSE=99` we can see why:

```
/usr/bin/swig2.0 -python -py3\ -builtin\ -extranative -Wall -outdir ...
```

It's "helpfully" escaping the spaces. How can I stop CMake from doing that?

I tried a couple of ideas to fix it:

- Separating the arguments out

  ```
  SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(example.i PROPERTIES SWIG_FLAGS "-py3", "-builtin", "-extranative")
  ```

  But that just ignores the second and third ones:

  ```
  /usr/bin/swig2.0 -python -py3 -Wall -outdir ....
  ```
- Using the `SEPARATE_ARGUMENTS` macro:

  ```
  SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(example.i PROPERTIES SWIG_FLAGS SEPARATE_ARGUMENTS("-py3 -builtin -extranative"))
  ```

  CMake fails with this though:

  ```
  set_source_files_properties called with incorrect number of arguments.
  ```

What's the way to pass multiple options correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the [set_property](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command%3aset_property) function instead of `set_source_files_properties`. This one allows the property value to be a CMake list:

```
set_property(SOURCE example.i PROPERTY SWIG_FLAGS "-py3" "-builtin" "-extranative")
```

Answer (score 0):

when you separate the flags with semicolons it will `SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES` accept them (tested on cmake 2.8.11) :

```
SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(example.i PROPERTIES SWIG_FLAGS "-py3;-builtin;-extranative;")
```